# Заполнение RecyclerView с разными Layout

Tags: java, android, listview, recyclerview

Я хочу сделать список с разделенными секциями используя `RecyclerView` (Как `ExpandableListView`). Чтобы определять тип элемента, я переопределяю метод  `getItemViewType()`.

Модели данных такие:

```
public static class Surah{
    int id;
    String title;
    List<Ayah> ayahs;

    public Surah(){}

    public Surah(int id, String title, List<Ayah> ayahs) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.ayahs = ayahs;
    }
}

public static class Ayah{
    int ayahId;
    String text;

    public Ayah(int ayahId, String text) {
        this.ayahId = ayahId;
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Примерно такая же структура моделей используется и в  ExpandableListView, но я не знаю как переопределить метод `onBindViewHolder()` чтобы заполнить список имея такую структуру данных. Такое возможно? Если да, дайте пример кода `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Похоже, то, что вам надо https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view. 19 секунд гугления.

Comment: @pavlofff как совместить айтемы я знаю. вопрос в том, как заполнить этот список данными.

Comment: Добавьте код адаптера, как вы пытались это сделать. Для ответа недостаточно информации

Comment: Дело в том, что я не пытался это делать, потому что не могу придумать как это сделать.

Comment: @metalurgus спасибо. если я все буду делать по гугловским библиотекам, далеко не пойду. Мне кажется самая большая проблема русскоязычных форумов - постоянно напоминать спрашивающему про гугл. Лично я задаю здесь вопрос только в крайнем случае, если несколько дней не могу решить задачу. Дело в том, что мне интересно не то, какую библиотеку лучше использовать, а как самому понять проблему и попытаться ее решить. Если не могу сам, то с вашей помощью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если в списке должны отображаться только `Surah` с раскрывающимся списком `Ayah` для каждой, то вам нужен только один тип элементов.
2. Каждый элемент разметки для Surah должен содержать в разметке контейнер для отображения списка `Ayah`.
3. В onBindViewHolder вы получаете по позиции конретную `Surah`.
4. Далее, циклом пробегаетесь по его списку `Ayah`, и добавляете их разметку в контейнер `Surah`.
5. Для раскрытия/скрытия списка `Ayah` вам надо контейнеру, в коем они лежат менять высоту с `0` на `wrap_content` через `LayoutParams` по клику на, например, заголовок  `Surah`.

Разметка должна как-то так выглядеть:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ayah_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```